# PayPal and tracking

Tags: paypal

I was thinking about setting up PayPal. One issue I have is tracking.

If I accept money today and want to refund it a year or two from now, do I have the proper tracking to know who sent me $$ and how much?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paypal provides you with pretty much all the details from their history tab. You can go search on specific dates

[image: date-range]

Clicking on details will give you the full details

[image: details]

Within the date-range you can drilldown to specific events

[image: filtering on different types of transactions.]

Comment: Oh nice. I was worried it only has it for the past 12months. Do you happen to know if the data can be exported so i can do something with it programatically? I probably won't need to although a batch check if list of transactions/emails exist would be nice

Comment: @acidzombie24 You can export the data as comma-separated, tab-separated file or as a PDF too